# Display file properties dialog for files in different directories

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I'm trying to open the default file properties dialog but unable to get it working property for files in different directories. 
I need to obtain `IContextMenu*` interface pointer for files in different directories (or even drives).
I expect to see "Various folders" in the properties dialog.

This is my naive approach:

```
int main() {
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    LPOLESTR pszFile = OLESTR("c:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
    LPOLESTR pszFile2 = OLESTR("c:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl2;
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlItem;
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlItem2;
    HRESULT hr;
    IShellFolder* pFolder;
    IContextMenu* pContextMenu;
    CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO cmi;

    hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&pFolder);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return 0;

    hr = pFolder->ParseDisplayName(HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, pszFile, NULL, &pidl, NULL);
    hr = pFolder->ParseDisplayName(HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, pszFile2, NULL, &pidl2, NULL);
    pFolder->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) return 0;

    hr = SHBindToParent(pidl, IID_IShellFolder, (void **)&pFolder, &pidlItem);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        SHFree(pidl);
        return 0;
    }
    //pFolder->Release();
    hr = SHBindToParent(pidl2, IID_IShellFolder, (void **)&pFolder, &pidlItem2);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        SHFree(pidl2);
        return 0;
    }

    LPCITEMIDLIST list[] = {pidlItem, pidlItem2};
    hr = pFolder->GetUIObjectOf(HWND_DESKTOP, 2, (LPCITEMIDLIST *)list, IID_IContextMenu, NULL, (void **)&pContextMenu);
    pFolder->Release();
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        ZeroMemory(&cmi, sizeof(cmi));
        cmi.cbSize = sizeof(cmi);
        cmi.lpVerb = "properties";
        cmi.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;

        hr = pContextMenu->InvokeCommand(&cmi);
        MessageBox(0, _T("Dummy message box"), 0, 0);
        Sleep(10000); // Give the system time to show the dialog before exiting
        pContextMenu->Release();
    }

    SHFree(pidl);

    return 0;
}
```

Also I tried [this](http://www.xworks.ca/coding/uiobject2.txt), but it also not working at all.
Also I tried to use desktop IShellFolder as parent of my PIDLs, but it also not working.

Any ideas?

[image: screenshot 2015-12-31 002.png]

[image: screenshot 2015-12-31 001.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf()` only works with single-level PIDLs that are relative to the `IShellFolder` being queried.  This is clearly stated in the [`GetUIObjectOf()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775073.aspx):

> The address of an array of pointers to ITEMIDLIST structures, each of which uniquely identifies a file object or subfolder **relative to the parent folder. Each item identifier list must contain exactly one SHITEMID structure followed by a terminating zero**.

You are converting the 2 absolute PIDLs into relative PIDLs of their respective folders, but then you are using the `IShellFolder` of the `Windows\System32` folder to retrieve the `IContextMenu` for both files. That will not work for the relative PIDL belonging to the `Windows\` folder, since the `IShellFolder` of the `Windows\System32` folder only knows about files in the `Windows\System32` folder.

Various online examples show the `IContextMenu` being queried from the `IShellFolder` of the desktop when multiple files are involved.  That approach only works when the files are in the same parent folder (such as demonstrated in [Raymond Chen's example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130617-00/?p=4073)).  Things get more complicated when the files are in different folders.

You also have a few memory leaks in your code.

The *correct* way to handle this situation is to use the [`SHMultiFileProperties()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762230.aspx) function:

> Displays a merged property sheet for a set of files. Property values common to all the files are shown while those that differ display the string (multiple values).

Use the `IShellFolder` of the desktop to get an `IDataObject` for the absolute PIDLs (this is one time where `GetUIObjectOf()` is allowed to violate the "Each item identifier list must contain exactly one SHITEMID structure" rule) and then pass that to `SHMultiFileProperties()`.  For example:

```
int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    LPOLESTR pszFile = OLESTR("c:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
    LPOLESTR pszFile2 = OLESTR("c:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl2;
    HRESULT hr;
    IShellFolder* pDesktop;
    IDataObject *pDataObject;

    hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&pDesktop);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CoUninitialize();
        return 0;
    }

    hr = pDesktop->ParseDisplayName(HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, pszFile, NULL, &pidl, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        pDesktop->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 0;
    }

    hr = pDesktop->ParseDisplayName(HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, pszFile2, NULL, &pidl2, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        SHFree(pidl);
        pDesktop->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 0;
    }

    LPCITEMIDLIST list[] = {pidl, pidl2};
    hr = pDesktop->GetUIObjectOf(HWND_DESKTOP, 2, (LPCITEMIDLIST *)list, IID_IDataObject, NULL, (void **)&pDataObject);
    // alternatively, you can also use SHCreateDataObject() or CIDLData_CreateFromIDArray() to create the IDataObject
    pDesktop->Release();
    SHFree(pidl);
    SHFree(pidl2);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = SHMultiFileProperties(pDataObject, 0);
        pDataObject->Release();

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            MessageBox(0, _T("Dummy message box"), 0, 0);
            Sleep(10000); // Give the system time to show the dialog before exiting
        }
    }

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way to archive the same behaviour with `IContextMenu`? As far as I understand, the file managers handle separately the menu item "Properties" and execute `SHMultiFileProperties` instead of `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand`, which is used for all other menu items?
But the menu is being displayed is completely functional, you can copy, cut , delete selected files even if they are in the different directories.

Comment: It *can* be achieved with `IContextMenu` but not easily. Raymond Chen said: [Get IContextMenu for files in diferent folders](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.ui/yA7idd95ljM) "*You'll have to write your own composite context menu. That's what Find Files does... It's not easy. You have to GetUIObjectOf(IContextMenu) for each object in your group, then take the intersection of all the menu items and put that as the context menu for the combination. Or you can do what the Find Files does and punt if there are multiple files of different filetypes.*"

Comment: I doubt writing a "composite context menu" would work for invoking the Properties dialog, though.  It would make more sense when invoking non-visual actions on files that implement the same verbs. You would simply loop through the collected `IContextMenu` objects calling the desired verb on each one.

Comment: Interesting observation that Total Commander's properties dialog is not working correctly for files on different DRIVES (the "General" tab is missing). It means that TotalCmd doesn't use  the `SHMultiFileProperties` function. I got the same issue when I wrote my test code with `IContextMenu`, and used `CSIDL_DRIVES` or something similar as parent for my PIDLs.

Comment: But Explorer and the nice utility for fast file search "Everything Search Engine" both show a correct context menu, and all items works like a charm. I really doubt that this tiny utility "Everything" takes the intersection of all the menu items to display them. There should be a system API for doing this. How do you make instersection of multiple menus ? How you can uniquely identify menu items? By id? or by their name?

Comment: Maybe they use `SHCreateDefaultContextMenu`

Comment: You might try using [`CDefFolderMenu_Create2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776389.aspx) (and its related cousin [`SHCreateDefaultContextMenu()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762127.aspx)) to get an `IContextMenu` for files spanning multiple folders. See [The multi-folder shell context menu riddle](http://www.zabkat.com/blog/08Jul07.htm) for a discussion about this topic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553835/how-to-display-system-context-menu-for-multiple-files-in-different-folders

Comment: I have researched this issue and figured out that Everything seems to be using `IShellView*` object, populating it somehow with different PIDLs and the all the job is done inside shell32.dll

Comment: Did you read the article I linked to in my last comment? It explains how to get an `IContextMenu` from `CDefFolderMenu_Create2()`

Comment: Yes, it is possible to achive this easily starting with Vista using `IExplorerBrowser` and `IResultsFolder`, need to embed explorer in your app, an example is provided with win7 sdk "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\winui\shell\appplatform\ExplorerBrowserCustomContents\ExplorerBrowserCustomContents.sln". You can add any PIDLs into `IResultsFolder`