# How to launch Windows Explorer with a custom Search Result

Tags: winapi, search, explorer

I am writing a Windows application, which collects (possibly hundreds of) names of files, all of which live in subfolders of one particular folder (which the user can select). The list is just a subset of all the files in the folders.

I do not want to implement a user-interface that offers all kinds of sorting and selection possibilities because Windows Explorer is always much better in this regard.

Is it there an API that allows me to launch Windows Explorer from my application such that it displays my list of files as if it were the result of a search operation?

Answer (score 2):

The Explorer saved search format (.search-ms) is [documented on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-savedsearchfileformat). The only downside is that it will perform the actual search when you open it, it does not contain a list of paths of files found.

If this is unacceptable then you will have to get your hands dirty deep in `IShellFolder` and friends.

If hosting your own window is acceptable then `IExplorerBrowser` will get you 99% of the way there. Call [`IExplorerBrowser::FillFromObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-iexplorerbrowser-fillfromobject) to fill the view with a custom list of files or manipulate the view directly. Example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553835/how-to-display-system-context-menu-for-multiple-files-in-different-folders).

If you must display the list in Explorer then I think you will have to bite the bullet and implement a [namespace extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-implement).

Comment: Hosting an Explorer window is definitely an option. Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shopenfolderandselectitems) function to open one particular folder.

```
LPCWSTR pszPathToOpen = L"C:\\Users\\strives";
PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;
if (SUCCEEDED(SHParseDisplayName(pszPathToOpen, 0, &pidl, 0, 0)))
{
    // we don't want to actually select anything in the folder, so we pass an empty
    // PIDL in the array. if you want to select one or more items in the opened
    // folder you'd need to build the PIDL array appropriately
    ITEMIDLIST idNull = { 0 };
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlNull[1] = { &idNull };
    SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl, 1, pidlNull, 0);
    ILFree(pidl);
}
```

Alternatively, you can call [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) on the folder directly to run its default action (which is normally to open in a browser window):

```
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "C:\\Users\\strives", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants a flat list including the files in the subfolders.

Comment: @Anders I think using `ShellExecute` can directly achieve the desired effect of OP, that is, open the Windows Explorer  directly.

Comment: IIUC, this approach just opens one folder and displays all its files. That is not what I need.